# How to have an UI component scrolling with my UITableView

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, customization, uisearchbar

I am trying to have a UI component stuck to my cells in a UITableView and scrolling with them...
It seems weird but a picture permits to understand the main point:

[image: Before Scrolling]
Before Scrolling

[image: during scroll]
During Scroll

I am trying to do the same effect but with other UI components (another UIVIew).
Do you have some hints to do this ?

- Is it a custom uitableviewcell inserted at start ?
- Is there an easy-to-implement hack ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Could you somehow emphasize the UI component you've meant? I'm really trying to get the idea but...

Comment: I am trying to have the same effect with a UISearchBar.

Comment: Where do you want to place those components? On the top of the table view or on each cell?

Comment: Just remove that UISearchBar from TAbleView header & place it in View & DecreaSE the Size of TableView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add any UIView and make it scroll with the table cells by placing the UIView in the table header. There is a special property for a table view, called tableHeaderView.

Use something like this:

```
UIView* my_custom_view;

// TODO: Alloc, and initialize the view

tableView.tableHeaderView = my_custom_view;
```